# Unity Netcode, how to run functions on server-side without depending on the client?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, unity-networking

So I'm using Unity's NetCode for game objects and I'm trying to be able to run a function that's located on the server when a client sends the order to.

First of all, I now how to use RPCs the problem with it is that the code that's run is allocated in the client build, this makes me ask if it is possible to change the code in the client build in order to run different code in the server.

For example, if I have an rpc managing basic movement of a player (when space is pressed increase the height by 1m). Is it possible to change the code on the client and increase the height by any number?

If this is possible, is there any way so that the client tells the server to jump and the server will make the player jump using the values safely stored in the server-side/run a function or script available in the server build?

Answer (score 0):

With standard NGO, an authoritative client can have its code changed and hacked so that clients can tell the server whatever it likes.

There are no automatic options, you're going to have to code them and work them out. Your options are:

1. Send the control input to the server and do all the movement logic there. This will cause some laggy movement between player's input and movement on the screen.
2. Move on the client, let the server check the movement to make sure it's sensible and then warn the client if they keep doing something outside the bounds of the calculations.
3. Move on the client, send movement to the server and calculate it there and then send the server calculations back to the client and perform a reconciliation (which is pretty complex due to lag). If you're going down this road, you're going to end up making most of the netcode yourself.